# Windows 10: Environment variable added, but not printed with 'echo'

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, environment-variables, echo

I added `LOG_LEVEL` as a system environment variable on Windows 10, and set its value as `INFO`.

Then (only after pressing OK and closing that window), I opened a command-line terminal and entered `echo %LOG_LERVEL%`, which printed... `%LOG_LEVEL%`.

When I try the same on an environment variable which had already been there before I added mine, for example - `echo %OS%`, it prints `Windows_NT`.

Now, I tried to close and reopen the command-line terminal in several different paths.

In one of them (which I can no longer reproduce now), the command indeed printed `INFO` (the value of my variable).

When I try the same thing using Power Shell (the new command-line terminal which Microsoft shoved into my system on the last update, forcing the old command-line to disappear from the context menu), things are even worse, as it doesn't recognize neither the variable that I have added nor other variables which were there before.

For the same example above, `echo %OS%` prints `%OS%`.

What is going on here?

Comment: PowerShell is completely different to the command line. Do not expect environment variables to work the same way. They are accessed from the `Env:` provider.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Thank you, but Power Shell was just another attempt after the initial one had failed. My main issue is the fact that it doesn't even work in the old command line terminal. So I would be grateful if you could propose a solution for the old command-line terminal. Thanks.

Comment: If you have an open `cmd.exe` or PowerShell window and set an environment variable using the GUI, the change will not propagate to the open window. You must restart your `cmd.exe` or PowerShell window to see the new variable.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: "only after pressing OK and closing that window" (quoting from the question).

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use `cmd.exe` or PowerShell; environment variable propagation works the same way. I can't reproduce it and have no issues setting or retrieving environment variables in either one.

Comment: @Rafal's edit was appropriate, so I have restored it.

Comment: I should say as an aside that your questions are still too chatty. Please take note of the edits made on your prior questions, and write new ones with more succinctness.

Comment: I sometimes give this advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Comment: @goodvibration To answer your question about "we", it's one of the [guidances given on how to use this network of sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/525551). To make it easier for everyone one else who comes across a question in the future, whether they are there to answer it or find an answer to a similar issue, posts should be kept as short as possible while still including all necessary information. That means "please"s and "thank you"s should be avoided; stick to the topic and let people answer. [There is no chit-chat](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Powershell is not cmd.exe..
If yu want to print out the value of a system variable in Powershell you can use

```
[Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%LOG_LEVEL%")
```

or call cmd.exe and perform the `echo` command you are used to like this

```
cmd.exe /c "echo %LOG_LEVEL%"
```

If you really hate powershell and want to return to the old cmd.exe, I believe you can (still) do that. Read here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027690/windows-powershell-is-replacing-command-prompt

Comment: Thanks, but that does not answer my initial and main problem - how come my environment variable is not printed **in the old command-line terminal**?

Comment: weird.. I cannot reproduce that. I'm on Windows 10 Pro version 1803 and for me it works as expected. Does the `set` command show your variable with the correct value?

Comment: I set it via GUI interface (i.e., by editing Windows System Environment Variables).

Comment: Does it make any difference if you run the comandline tool as admin or user?

Comment: `$env:LOG_LEVEL` is actually how you'd reference it in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't make a dumb mistake like me and type the variable name in wrong.
In my case it took me a while (even after checking it) to notice I'd set my variable as JAVE_HOME not JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

If you used 'set' from withing a commandline window, then that creates a temporary enviroment variable that is lost when you close the window. If you want a permanent one you can use 'setx' or use the system properties dialog in Control Panel.